# Product of Symmetric and Antisymmetric Tensors

Tags: tensor-products

I would like to know if the following product is antisymmetric in 4 dimensions. All tensor elements are real valued.
$${T_\mu}^{\nu}$$ T is a 4 dimensional symmetric tensor with mixed indices. $${\epsilon^{(3)}}_{\nu \rho \sigma }$$ epsilon^(3) is the Levi-Civita tensor with 3 indices in 4 dimensions.
$$A=T \epsilon^{(3)}$$
Is the tensor A antisymmetric? Does it have 3 independent components?

Comment: Is this a tensor product of two tensors or is there a contraction somewhere within?